# Applying an operation to the rows of a matrix, except for some rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` matrix `M` and I need to apply some operations to all the rows of the matrix, except for a determined rows.

For example, suppose I have rows `[3,5]` whose elements should be avoided from an operation like `M[:,8] = 4`. So I want to have all the rows of the 8th column to be set to 4, but I want to avoid doing so to rows 3 and 5. How can I do this in `numpy`?

**Edit**: basically I need that to avoid a division by zero when doing a normalization by the sum of the elements of a row. Some rows are all zeros, so doing the summation (which is zero) then dividing by the summation will give a division by zero. What I'm doing is that I find out which rows are all zeros and then I want not to do the normalization operation for those specific rows.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.arange(32).reshape(8, 4)
>>> ignore = {3, 5}
>>> rest = [i for i in xrange(M.shape[0]) if i not in ignore]
>>> M[rest, 3] = 4
>>> M
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  4],
       [ 8,  9, 10,  4],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18,  4],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26,  4],
       [28, 29, 30,  4]])
```

Comment: there must be a more efficient way!

Comment: @AlexTwain As per your edit how about  `M[np.where(M[:,8]!=0)[0], 8] = 4` ?

Comment: The indexing seems pretty efficient to me ..., maybe a binary mask is better in some cases. Of course the construction of `rest` can be done better, but this doesn't take much time here. Also `rest` should be an array to avoid some serious jokes that by luck do not happen when indexing in the first axis, but can happen on other axes. Otherwise this solution seems pretty much OK to me. Is your application still the google matrix? In this case you should indicate that your matrix is enormous and sparse, because that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, in order to solve your specific problem, where you seem to manipulating a matrix with **non-negative** entries, you may exploit the following trick

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
M = rng.randn(10, 10) ** 2
M[[0, 5]] = 0.  # set 2 lines to 0

M_norm = M / (M.sum(axis=1) + 1e-18)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Obviously this result is not exact, but exact enough to not notice the difference. To make it slightly better, you can also write

```
M_norm = M / np.maximum(M.sum(axis=1), 1e-18)[:, np.newaxis]
```

If this still isn't sufficient, and you want it exact, for the **general case** (negativity allowed) you can write

```
row_sums = M.sum(axis=1)
row_sums[row_sums == 0] = 1.

M_norm = M / row_sums[:, np.newaxis]  # dividing the zeros by 1 still yields 0
```

To add some robustness, you could also do

```
tolerance = 1e-6

row_sums = M.sum(axis=1)
OK_rows = np.abs(row_sums) > tolerance
M_norm = np.zeros_like(M)
M_norm[OK_rows] = M[OK_rows] / row_sums[OK_rows][:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Using sparse matrices you may have to adapt a few things.